# Cache Shows Old Values on IIS7, not Debug Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, caching, static

I have a pretty standard MVC3 application. I'm trying to store some data that's application-wide (not user wide) in a the cache (in this case, a `Theme` object/name). When debugging (on the development server that integrates with Visual Studio), if I call `SwitchTheme`, I see the new theme right away. On IIS7, whatever theme was cached, stays cached; it doesn't update to the new theme.

**Edit:** Some code:

```
    public static Theme CurrentTheme { get {
        Theme currentTheme = HttpContext.Current.Cache[CURRENT_THEME] as Theme;

        if (currentTheme == null)
        {
            string themeName = DEFAULT_THEME;
            try
            {
                WebsiteSetting ws = WebsiteSetting.First(w => w.Key == WebsiteSetting.CURRENT_THEME);

                if (ws != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ws.Value))
                {
                    themeName = ws.Value;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // DB not inited, or we're installing, or something broke.
                // Don't panic, just use the default.
            }

            // Sets HttpContext.Current.Cache[CURRENT_THEME] = new themeName)
            Theme.SwitchTo(themeName);
            currentTheme = HttpContext.Current.Cache[CURRENT_THEME] as Theme;

        }

        return currentTheme;
    } }

public static void SwitchTo(string name)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(CURRENT_THEME, new Theme(name), null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));

        // Persist change to the DB.
        // But don't do this if we didn't install the application yet.
        try
        {
            WebsiteSetting themeSetting = WebsiteSetting.First(w => w.Key == WebsiteSetting.CURRENT_THEME);
            if (themeSetting != null)
            {
                themeSetting.Value = name;
                themeSetting.Save();
            }
            // No "else"; if it's not there, we're installing, or Health Check will take care of it.
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // DB not inited or install not complete. No worries, mate.
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure where the problem is. I am calling the same method and updating the cache; but IIS7 just shows me the old version.

I can disable output caching in IIS, but that's not what I want to do. That seems like a hacky work-around at best.

Comment: You need to post code samples.

Comment: Are you getting app pool resets in the system event log? (also, do you have IIS configured to log app pool resets to the event log) I had this problem once, and it was because we had configured a virtual memory limit that was too low. As a result, every request would reset the app pool which would empty my static objects.

Comment: @Ek0nomik what kind of code? There's so much I could show. Web.config?

Comment: A code sample is necessary, but utilizing my psychic debugging skills, the tea leaves tell me you're setting your static variable to null in its declaration (e.g. private static string _myData = null;) or something similar.

Comment: @RobertC.Barth that wasn't the case, but sure, here's some code with attempted caching.

Comment: @ZachGreen nope, nothing there; just application pools timing out after 20 minutes (which is normal, I think)

Comment: You never set the cache item; you're only reading from it. You probably want to just cache the name of the theme, not a Theme object itself, so there are a couple of changes you'll want to make.

Comment: Also, it's bad practice to do that much work in a property getter. You should give some thought to turning it into a function.

Comment: @RobertC.Barth I'm doing it in Theme.SetCurrentTheme(...). Added a comment for that. Yep, I will do that as soon as I get this static var issue solved.

Comment: @ashes999 - Post the code same where you **set** the cache.

Comment: Regarding your comment "Sets HttpContext.Current.Cache[CURRENT_THEME] = new themeName)", that's not what that next line of code does... it READS the cache, it does not SET anything...

Comment: @RobertC.Barth `Theme.SwitchTo` updates the cache. I've posted the code.

Comment: I see, however, what is the purpose of the line "currentTheme = HttpContext.Current.Cache[CURRENT_THEME] as Theme;" at the end of the getter of CurrentTheme?

Comment: @RobertC.Barth that's the return value. I have to return the current theme.

Comment: You did that at the top of the getter, currentTheme will have the same value in both places as the cache value has not changed.

Comment: Oh, nm, I see, I missed the switchTo part... this caching scheme is extremely brittle. Generally, you want to cache after you're sure your write succeeded and not before. You may also want to think about caching just the string name and not the Theme object.

Comment: @RobertC.Barth okay, thanks, I will do that. But, why does IIS7 show me the old theme even when I update the cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that this only happens on IIS7 when Output Caching is not disabled, this seems very likely to be an IIS7 bug. Seriously.

Whether it is or not, is irrelevant to the solution. What you need to do is find some manual process of invalidating the cache, such as touching the web.config file.

But beware: doing this will wipe out the cache (as you expect), but also all static variables (as a side-effect). Whether this is another bug or not, I don't know; but in my case, this was sufficient to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Without a code sample it's difficult to know what your problem is.  In an attempt to provide some assistance, here is how I frequently set the cache in my applications:

```
    public static void SetCache(string key, object value) {
        if (value != null) {
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(key, value, null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Ek0nomic it's mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I'm getting cached results. Calling SwitchTheme(...) shows me the old (cached) theme in IIS, not the new theme, despite me setting the value as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP cache is reset only if you do so manually or the app domain (or app pool) resets for whatever reason. Are you sure that's not happening in this case? And generally speaking, any global static variables would also be maintained in memory under the same circumstances.

There are many reasons why an app pool might be reset at any given point, such as a change to a web.config file, etc. I suggest checking that's not happening in your case.

By the way, output caching is a different thing, although it is maintained in memory largely the same way.

Comment: Any clues about the IIS caching issue?

Comment: Never used themes so no, sorry. But if you've turned off IIS caching then it's probably the browser's fault; you need to modify your app's output caching parameters to force the browser to stop doing that.

Comment: themes are irrelevant, unless it's something about me changing the layout that's caching specific. Like my question says, if I disable output caching completely the problem disappears; so it MUST be IIS, no?